# Insert bash env vars as text from terminal

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I want to update my `.bashrc` to include this alias:

```
alias j7='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_7_HOME && export JRE_HOME=$JRE_7_HOME && export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$JAVA_PATH'
```

By doing as below:

```
[... ~]$ echo "alias j7='export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_7_HOME && export JRE_HOME=$JRE_7_HOME && export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/bin:$JAVA_PATH'" | sudo tee -a '~/.bashrc'
alias j7='export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80 && export JRE_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre && export PATH=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80/bin:/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_80/jre/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'
```

I do not want the variables `$JAVA_7_HOME` etc to be substituted by their values. How can I insert $JAVA_7_HOME as text?

Comment: Why are you trying to echo it and not using s text editor ?  You should just have enclose it in single quotes and / or escape all the $s.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes or add a backslah before the dollar sign

If you use single quotes you need to insert a backslash before each single quote inside the string

Comment: If you're using single quotes, you need the sequence `'\''` to embed a single quote:  `echo 'He said, "Don'\''t do it; I wouldn'\''t do it if I were you!"'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a backslash before the dollar sign:

```
echo "\$JAVA_7_HOME"
```